# java - can a class type parameter from a static main class be passed to another class

Tags: java

I have 2 classes the static `main` class and class `B`. I'm trying to pass `main` to `B`, where there is a method that sets fields.

Can this be done?

If so, could you please provide examples?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList a = new ArrayList()
class b = new class()

b.update(b);
}

class a {
public void update(ArrayList a) {
   //updates the encapsulated arrayList field
   }
}
```

The error message keeps on saying that one is static and the other is non-static, but they should be pointing the same object

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens :)?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the class or an instance of the class?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You are going to have to clarify the question before anybody can answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but here is an example that shows that you can pass an instance of the main class into another class:

```
public class A {
    private String str = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(a);

        System.out.println(a.getStr());
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return this.str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}

public class B {
    public B(A a) {
        a.setA("hello");
    }
}
```

Running this code will print out `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

main is static and public, so you can call it from any other class as any other public static method: statically.

if you have a class A that contains a

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method, then class B can call this method like

```
A.main(s);
```

where s is String[]

your question is far from clear, so I suggest you to add more code samples to make it clear what you're really trying to do.